# Qt QML: Convert shader effects for use with new Direct3D 11 RHI

Tags: qt, qml, shader, qtquick2, direct3d

Since version 5.14, Qt supports a preview of the upcoming scene graph backends with RHI. We have tried it with our C++/Qt application using the d3d11 backend on Windows 10. It works great: RAM usage of our application went down tremendously and the animations are now way smoother than with the old opengl backend. We would like to switch to the new backend, however the ShaderEffects (such as DropShadow or Glow) are not yet working.

I found an [explanation on the Qt blog](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-quick-on-vulkan-metal-and-direct3d-part-3), but I do not understand how to convert shaders to the new format (.qsb) and how to use them in QML with the new direct3d11 RHI. Is this even possible already?